# Vue Static files are not loading

Tags: python, django, vue.js

So I am developing a django application and using vue for frontend.
I have connected the vue app and the django app using `views.py`.
But when I am trying to run the application for some reason django is not loading the static files properly.

Here is my settings.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-^**********************************'


DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'store_closure.apps.StoreClosureConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'corsheaders',
    'CapstoneProject',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'CapstoneProject.urls'
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True   

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'CapstoneProject.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '*****',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATIC_ROOT = 'var/static_root/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles/'
print(ROOT_PATH)
print(STATICFILES_DIRS)

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

The static files are in the root folder in `static/src/vue/dist`

When I run the application, the page shows a form and a map components from vue but they are styled as they should be.

Comment: Do you run collectstatic? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic

Comment: No, should I add it?
 According to the link you attached, it's a function for development version, which I am not using.

Comment: Check this one: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic
you have to pick version you use